# how to concatenate path with variables from source file

Tags: bash, source

I have a source file that contains
 some variables, for example,

```
 locate=$HOME
```

and a shell script that contains

```
. .foorc


cat ${locate}/file.txt
```

I get cat error with the "no such file" mention.
Every file is in its assigned directory..

What did I do wrong?

Thanks,
Raphael

Comment: you should be able to assign the variables with `source .foorc` and the write `cat "$locate"/file.txt`

Comment: The problem actually comes from the "$locate",

    `echo $locate`

does not print anything

nor `echo ${locate}`

nor `echo "$locate"`

Comment: So you said  "for example", but the actual directory that you assign to the variable is different. Does it have spaces or any special characters in the path of that directory  ?  Also, try changing the variable. There is a shell command known as `locate`, so try different naming. `targedDir=$HOME` for instance

Comment: I believe, you want to read the variables asigned in `.foorc` into your script with the line `. .foorc`, right? Then, try to use `source .foorc` instead

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables declared in a file by using `source filename` in your shell script.

---

Example:
This is how my directory looks like:

```
.
├── .foorc
├── foo.sh
└── testdir
    └── file.txt
```

The content of `.foorc`:

```
directory="./testdir"
word="World"
```

The content of `file.txt`:

```
foo-bar
```

The content of `foo.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

source .foorc

echo "Hello $word"
cat "$directory"/file.txt
```

Now, running`./foo.sh` results in:

```
Hello World
foo-bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I assumed that if the `cat` function couldn't find the file, it was a problem due to the working directory.
I added `cd` to the directory I seemed to be in and problem solved

```
cd ${location}
cat file.txt
```

Thank you for your very thorough answer.